# Find the matrix $A^{15}$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $I=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $O=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

---

1.Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $ B=\begin{pmatrix}
x & 3 \\
3 & 6 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$. Find the value of $x$ which satisfies $AB=BA$.

$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x & 3 \\
3 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x+9 & 21 \\
3x+15 & 39 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$BA=\begin{pmatrix}
x & 3 \\
3 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x+9 & 3x+15 \\
21 & 39 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
.So that we get $3x+15=21 \Rightarrow x=2$

---

2.Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $ B=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & x \\
4 & y \\
\end{pmatrix}$.Find the values of x and y which satify $BA=O$.
$BA=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & x \\
4 & y \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-2+2x & 0 \\
4+2y & 8+4y \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

S0 that we can get $x=1,y=-2$.

---

3.Let $A$ satisfying $A^2=A-I$. Find $A^{15}$.

Please help to show me about this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Hint* Compute $A^3$ first.

Comment: Have you try to find a formula giving $A^n$ by induction? $A^3 = A^2 \cdot A=A^2-A=-I$ for example.

Comment: Ok thank I will try.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Induction isn't necessary because $A^{15}=(A^3)^5$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Good remark that makes it simple!

Comment: Items 1 and 2 are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You may proceed as follows:

From the given condition we have

$$A-A^2 = A(I-A) =I$$

It follows

\begin{eqnarray} A^{15}
& = & A(A^2)^7 \\
& = & A(A-I)^7 \\
& = & -(A-I)^6 \\
& = & -(A^2-2A + I)^3 \\
& = & -(-A)^3 \\
& = & A(A-I) \\
& = & -I
\end{eqnarray}

Another way would be seeing

$$A^3+I = (A+I)(A^2-A+I)=O \Rightarrow A^3 = -I$$

Comment: Ok now I can do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you recognize $x^2-x+1$ as a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), then
$$x^{15} + 1 = (x^3+1)a(x) = (x^2-x+1)b(x)$$ gives $A^{15}+I=0$.

The systematic way, which does not need insights, is to use polynomial division:
$$
x^{15}=(x^2-x+1)q(x)-1
$$
where $q(x)=x^{13} + x^{12} - x^{10} - x^9 + x^7 + x^6 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1$ is not really relevant. Only the remainder matters here.